# How to install Lubuntu without GUI installer?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, lubuntu

I want to install Lubuntu on an embedded system. I can connect display and keyboard, but no mouse, so only CLI installation is possible. Although I need the complete (not server) distribution because I want to connect to the computer using VNC. Thank you for help.

Comment: If this other question does not solve your problem please [edit] and clarify why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server version uses the text installer. Maybe it's easier to go on with it and install later a meta-package like lubuntu-desktop